# How best to join multiple SVG Files info 1?

Tags: svg, data-merge, file-management

While I do realize that this question has bee n asked, and answered, the answers seems to have very mixed results, and unfortunately, the reasoning for the joining in the posts I have found appear to be very different from what I need. So here I am to ask to see if someone can provide a solution or recommendation that is right for what I am in need of.

I have a number of SVG files that are each pages of a larger document, and I would like to be able to combine them into one single file.

The files are not being used on a web page, or anything like that.  The previous questions posted on this were asking for SVG image files such as icons or some other images, that were then meant to be used on a web page.

However, in my case, I have for example,, a 30 page example of a Business Plan. Each page of the plan is it's own SVG file. I would like to some how join the images together into one and then either export it to a PDF or Word type format so that (if possible) the text will not be seen as an image and I could modify the document for my needs.

While I do believe concatenating the the multiple files may actually be the easy part, however, since their currently in an SVG format,I don't know if the text mapping exists, and if anything would be able to recognize the text as anything but an image.

I did try using Inkscape since that's one of the better free Vector Image Applications however, while the SVG files are valid, and can be opened on a browsers,  (Chrome) for viewing with no issue, Inkscape crashes when I trying to open one of the files with it.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, and as a reminder, these images will not be using on a website or anything like that, the intent is to open and edit them in Windows which I know can not be done as they are now.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you share one of the SVG files?

Comment: My apologies for doing this rather in a difficult fashion, but  the site here would not allow me to upload the SVG files, and I couldn't figure out how to attach a Zip file or anything, so I uploaded them to my website, and yo can download them using these links..

https://systopian.com/uploads/1/2/9/7/129723245/refund-policy-page1.svg
https://systopian.com/uploads/1/2/9/7/129723245/refund-policy-page2.svg

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the file.  I'll post an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Im sure you have figured this by now but use a browser to print each svg to ghostwiew Or actobat pdf files then use ghostwiew to comcatenate the files.

Answer (score 0):

I got your sample SVG to open in Inkscape 0.92.3, but I can see it contains lots of bitmap images, there are no vectors at all, and they contain no editable text.  I'm not sure why you can't open them in Inkscape.  Perhaps check your Inkscape version.

From Inkscape you could then export each page as a PNG. Then import them into your favourite word processor, one placed on each page, then export as PDF.  MS Word and LibreOffice Writer can export PDFs.

If you can't get Inkscape to play nice, I suppose you could try opening them in GIMP, export as PNG, and do the same.

If you want an editable text document, it might be just as easy to re-type the entire document in a word processor to be honest, or perhaps use OCR software.

Comment: Unfortunately, retyping while an options for a couple of the smaller documents, really wouldn't work to well for the one that has 79 pages! 

When I try to open in Inkspace, it hangs and crashes and on the couple times it opened, there was nothing remotely legible , however, if I open the same file in Chrome, it looks beautiful, just like a PDF . So I guess my next question would be, is there any reason that the files should not be able to be printed to a  Word format using the Word Print to File Print Driver? Because I did try, and that didn't work either. Thank you very much

Comment: Not sure if you understand what I'm saying. The problem is that there is no editable text the document. It's made up of bitmap images only. These can't be edited in a word processor.

Comment: Yes I did understand that. My intent want to edit them as SVG's but being able to covert them into a format where I can. While I underhand your saying the text is made up as bitmaps images I am assuming that converting them (which I found a windows batch script that calls Inkscape to convert them from SVG to PDF, it's a bit buggy because it does't convert all the images and Im not sure why) however, it must use something like OCR to convert the bitmaps to text because once in PDF format, I am able to copy and paste the text. So at least with that I am able to copy the text out to a new file.

Comment: I can always copy the text into a writer format (Word, TextMaker, etc). Now, the last question, is there anyway to get them to combine into 1 multistage file? Or is that just asking too much at this time?? Cheers

Comment: @JohnDurchak Inkscape has no OCR functionality.